# Zebra ZT410 programming RFID UserMemory

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using a Zebra ZT410 for printing a very simple label with a single barcode and encoding a SMARTRAC Frog 3D RFID tag with a Monza 4D chip on it.

My goal is to also program RFID User Memory on the RFID tag, but I can't write more than 4 bytes before the printer starts printing void labels.

This prints a barcode and programs the EPC memory on the RFID tag (no User Memory programming):

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD25012345678^FS
^RB96,8,28,16,8,36
^RFW,E
^FD53.1000.250.0.12345678^FS
^XZ
```

This does the same as above, but also programs 4 bytes of user memory:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD25012345678^FS
^RB96,8,28,16,8,36
^RFW,E
^FD53.1000.250.0.12345678^FS
^RFW,H,,4,3^FD12345678^FS
^XZ
```

Programming more than 4 bytes of user memory results in void tags:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD25012345678^FS
^RB96,8,28,16,8,36
^RFW,E
^FD53.1000.250.0.12345678^FS
^RFW,H,,8,3^FD1234567812345678^FS
^XZ
```

What am I doing wrong?

/Mogens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specification page for the Monza 4D tag (Impinj)](https://www.impinj.com/platform/endpoints/monza-4d/), the Monza 4D only has 32 bits of user memory.  That's 4 bytes.  The printer's only way to deal with the error of trying to encode more data than the chip is capable of is to void the tag.

Comment: Hi Mogens, did this help?  There are other Impinj tags with more user memory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes that helped. We had a roll of these tags, but we forgot that they had so little User Memory.